# SigninwithIntuit with multiple user of the same QuickBook Company

Tags: intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online

I've successfully Integrated my application with QuickBook Online. I successfully implemented `DirectConnectToIntuit`, `SigninWithIntuit`, `Disconnect` scenario and Test according to https://developer.intuit.com/docs/@api/deki/files/3143/recipe_for_review_success.pdf. I have a situation with `DirectConnectToIntuit`, `SigninWithIntuit` for multiple user. Consider the `SigninWithIntuit` scenerio:

When a first user comes, they click `SigninWithIntuit` in my application, add their username and password, authorize by Intuit and comeback in my site. As the user is new and his email address is not in my database, I show him the account creation form. When this user submits the form after filling it in then I the create database entry, create the user etc, then login and show `ConnectToQuickBook` button(G. in the above doc). Everything is OK up to now.

When another user is created in the same QuickBooks online company, then this new user clicks on `SignInWithIntuit` in my application, and they come back to my app after authorization. For this user, I will not show the account Creation form, I just create this new user and assign as a user of the previous created company, login and show the `ConnectToIntuit` button. But how can I determine the company of the user? I don't have an access token or access token secret yet to do that.

Comment: I reworded your question to make it more obvious what you are asking. Breaking your question up into paragraphs is always helpful. It would be helpful if you included code where you're trying to `ConnectToIntuit`. I also added the QB online tag so you should hopefully get more help. Always add tags that are helpful so the right people see your question.

Answer (score 0):

It is answered here (Intuit's live community) - 
https://intuitdeveloper.lc.intuit.com/questions/1188167-signinwithintuit-with-multiple-user-of-the-same-quickbook-company?jump_to=answer_2643393

Comment: Thanks for your answer.Can you please suggest me one or more option.That will be very helpfull

Comment: Thanks for your answer.Can you please suggest me one or more specific option to identify new user of an existing company in my application.That will be very helpfull

Comment: The link to the intuit developer question is broken, it might have moved.