# SigninwithIntuit with multiple user(the same QuickBook Company)

Tags: quickbooks

I've successfully Integrated my application with QuickBook Online. I successfully implemented DirectConnectToIntuit, SigninWithIntuit, Disconnect scenario and Test according to https://developer.intuit.com/docs/@api/deki/files/3143/recipe_for_review_success.pdf. I have a situation with DirectConnectToIntuit, SigninWithIntuit for multiple user. Consider the SigninWithIntuit scenerio:

When a first user comes, they click SigninWithIntuit in my application, add their username and password, authorize by Intuit and comeback in my site. As the user is new and his email address is not in my database, I show him the account creation form. When this user submits the form after filling it in then I the create database entry, create the user etc, then login and show ConnectToQuickBook button(G. in the above doc). Everything is OK up to now.

When another user is created in the same QuickBooks online company, then this new user clicks on SignInWithIntuit in my application, and they come back to my app after authorization. For this user, I will not show the account Creation form, I just create this new user and assign as a user of the previous created company, login and show the ConnectToIntuit button. But how can I determine the company of the user? I don't have an access token or access token secret yet to do that.

Can you please suggest me one or more specific option to identify new user of an existing company in my application.That will be very helpful

thanks
sabbir

Comment: Are you using the standard SSO or modified SSO authorization flows? During their authorization sign on process a user will pick which company to use with your app, then you could use the CompanyInfo request to learn more about it. See here: https://developer.intuit.com/docs/api/accounting/CompanyInfo

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SigninwithIntuit with multiple user of the same QuickBook Company](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31401081/signinwithintuit-with-multiple-user-of-the-same-quickbook-company)

Comment: This is a direct copy + paste of your previous question.